# Shaliach Tzibur saying personal prayer in Shema Koleinu

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, hefsek-interruption

Recently I was in a Shul and the Shaliach Tzibur while saying the loud Shemona Esrei stopped in the middle of Shema Koleinu and quietly said a personal prayer.

Having never seen this done before, I am wondering is this permitted? Are there sources that discuss this?

Comment: If a chazzan forgets Aneinu in its proper place on a fast day, he adds it in shma koleinu. In some communities in Israel the chazzan adds aloud a request for rain there during a drought. In many communities the chazzan adds piyyutim in various places in prayers. But all these are public additions. I can't think of any reason to allow him to say quiet things in public prayer. At least it's Tircha deTzibbura.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Agreed, I thought it was strange, however before I said something to the fellow, wanted to know if I was correct.

Comment: I mean, in many places the chazzan says various parts of the piyyutim quietly. I have no way to justify that either, but at least we can say that if the tzibbur has agreed to tolerate such a practice it's probably not a formal hefsek.